# Does driver exist for Trendnet AC1200 Dual Band Wireless adapter for Ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, usb

I'm new to Ubuntu and was wondering if Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit drivers exist for the Trendnet AC1200 Dual Band Wireless USB 3.0 adapter. I tried searching the forums for my specific adapter, but no luck. Does such a driver exist? If not, can I use a generic driver for this adapter?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: lsusb Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You can check with the following command in your terminal**

```
sudo lshw -C network | grep driver
```